Very strange \edef l3backend-luatex.def{Foo} or \edef ⟨file name⟩{Foo} (not created by me)
(This is a follow-up of a previous question of mine.)
The following MCE works as expected:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \_add_data:n {
  % Here, we use different clists, otherwise sorting (line 30, below) doesn't
  % work
  \int_incr:N \g_tmpa_int
  \clist_new:c {g_tmpa_ \int_use:N \g_tmpa_int _clist}
  % Here, we pass data not directly but through a token list because in our real
  % use case, this is done via l3keys (... .tl_gset:N = ...)
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  % Here we use \clist_gset:ce instead of \clist_gset:cn, otherwise only the last
  % entered data is taken in account
  \clist_gset:ce {g_tmpa_ \int_use:N \g_tmpa_int _clist} {
    \g_tmpa_tl
  }
  % The data added is a clist which contains a token list and is gathered in
  % a sequence instead of a clist (see
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731213/18401) 
  \seq_gput_right:Nv \g_tmpa_seq {g_tmpa_ \int_use:N \g_tmpa_int _clist}
}

% We add two datas
\_add_data:n {
  Foo
  % \textsc{Foo}
}
\_add_data:n {
  Bar
}

% We sort the data
\seq_sort:Nn \g_tmpa_seq
{
  \str_compare:eNeTF { ##1 } > { ##2 }
  { \sort_return_swapped: }
  { \sort_return_same: }
}

% Each item of the sequence is a list which is stored in a temporary list which
% is first displayed and whose first and, here (not in my real use case), only
% element is left in the input stream (here printed).
\seq_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \clist_show:N \g_tmpa_clist
  \clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

But, as soon as the data contains commands (for instance, replace Foo by \textsc{Foo}), it doesn't work anymore and the shown content of \g_tmpa_clist looks very strange since, instead of:
The comma list \g_tmpa_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {Foo}.

we get:
The comma list \g_tmpa_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \edef l3backend-luatex.def{Foo}\let
\futurelet \@let@token \let \scshape Foo\egroup }.
<recently read> }

where \edef l3backend-luatex.def{Foo} seems very odd.
If the data is added in an auxiliary file, say data.tex, which is input in the main file, we get the equally strange  \edef data.tex{Foo} in place of \edef l3backend-luatex.def{Foo}:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.tex}
\_add_data:n {
  % Foo
  \textsc{Foo}
}
\_add_data:n {
  Bar
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \_add_data:n {
  % Here, we use different clists, otherwise sorting (line 30, below) doesn't
  % work
  \int_incr:N \g_tmpa_int
  \clist_new:c {g_tmpa_ \int_use:N \g_tmpa_int _clist}
  % Here, we pass data not directly but through a token list because in our real
  % use case, this is done via l3keys (... .tl_gset:N = ...)
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  % Here we use \clist_gset:ce instead of \clist_gset:cn, otherwise only the last
  % entered data is taken in account
  \clist_gset:ce {g_tmpa_ \int_use:N \g_tmpa_int _clist} {
    \g_tmpa_tl
  }
  % The data added is a clist which contains a token list and is gathered in
  % a sequence instead of a clist (see
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731213/18401) 
  \seq_gput_right:Nv \g_tmpa_seq {g_tmpa_ \int_use:N \g_tmpa_int _clist}
}

\input{data}

% We sort the data
\seq_sort:Nn \g_tmpa_seq
{
  \str_compare:eNeTF { #1 } > { #2 }
  { \sort_return_swapped: }
  { \sort_return_same: }
}

% Each item of the sequence is a list which is stored in a temporary list which
% is first displayed and whose first and, here (not in my real use case), only
% element is left in the input stream (here printed).
\seq_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \clist_show:N \g_tmpa_clist
  \clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

How do you explain this phenomenon and how can you enable commands in the data added?

Try removing the \clist_show:N and you'll get a different error.

What exactly is the end goal here?

@daleif Yes, the error is then ! Missing control sequence inserted. <inserted text> \inaccessible which can be seen with \clist_show:N when compilation continuation is forced.

In my real use case, the data added is ⟨last name⟩, ⟨first name⟩ and short ⟨biography⟩ of persons and these data has to be printed by alphabetic order of the last names, in a description list: `\begin{description}\item[⟨first name 1⟩ ⟨last name 1⟩] ⟨biography 1⟩ \item[⟨first name 2⟩ ⟨last name 2⟩] ⟨biography ⟩ [...] \end{description}

You want \clist_gset:co not \clist_gset:ce, and \clist_item:Nn. And do you really, really want to create a new clist everytime you add data?? Why don't you use one temporary clist?

@UlrikeFischer In fact, it does the trick! And, thanks to it, there's no need for a new list every time: thank you! But could you explain why expansion once did the trick?

You never should do e-expansion (or x-expansion or \edef or \xdef) on something that can contain arbitrary commands. In your case expanding only once is enough, if you need more use \text_expand:n or \protected@edef , they try to protect commands.

You have a classic fragile command in a moving argument error, where expansion is happening in expansion-only contexts e arguments in completely the wrong order, and with the wrong values/

If you want to add an item contained in a token list to a clist, use \clist_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl.
